# Does any group have plans for manned missions longer than the 5 year Callisto mission?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, future-missions

I understand the five-year duration of the HOPE Callisto mission to be at the edge of future manned missions for NASA. Are there any missions planned to be longer than that, by NASA or anyone else?

Further reading:

- [Revolutionary Concepts for Human Outer Planet Exploration (HOPE)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20030063128.pdf)
- [High Power MPD Nuclear Electric Propulsion (NEP) for Artificial Gravity HOPE Missions to Callisto](https://trajectory.grc.nasa.gov/aboutus/papers/STAIF-2003-177.pdf)
- [NASA Spaceflight forum: Humans to Callisto study](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=31983.0)

Comment: I suspect not and even if there was any relation to reality would be tenuous

Comment: Interesting to read about, food for thought at least...

Comment: Do proposals to colonize Mars with one way trips count?